# Perl: read data file as hash

Tags: perl

I have configuration file as follows:

```
 Name=test
 Password = test
```

I need to read the data file and set it as map so that I can set the data. Now, I have tried in this way:

```
$path_to_file ="C:\\Perl\\bin\\data.txt";
open(FILE, $path_to_file) or die("Unable to open file");
@data = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
print "data is ",$data[0],"\n";
```

But I am not getting the desired output. I get the output as  Name=test.

Comment: ConfigReader::Simple reads this sort of configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [Tie::File::AsHash](http://search.cpan.org/~cangell/Tie-File-AsHash-0.08/lib/Tie/File/AsHash.pm).

```
use Tie::File::AsHash;
tie my %map, Tie::File::AsHash::, $path_to_file, split => qr/\s*=\s*/, join => '='
 or die "failed to open: $!";
$map{Password} = 'swordfish'; # this actually changes the file!
print 'The password is ', $map{Password}, "\n";
```

Comment: I think he didn't mean to be able to modify the underlying file.

Comment: Well, I might be misinterpreting "I need to [...] set it as map so that i can set the data"

Comment: Notice that to use this module, you still have to do all the work to handle the data yourself. That `split` is doing most of the work and could be dropped into the original code.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
# open FILE as usual
my %map;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    # get rid of the line terminator
    chomp $line;
    # skip malformed lines.  for something important you'd print an error instead
    next unless $line =~ /^(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)$/;
    # insert into %map
    $map{$1} = $2;
}

# %map now has your key => value mapping
say "My name is: ", $map{Name};
```

Note that this allows white space around the equal sign.  You can easily modify it to also allow it at the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: But, how can i retrieve the value back from map

Comment: In the normal perlish manner: $map{Name} will then be 'test'.  I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: I tried the same. I dont get the value. I tried the following $map{Name} and also $map{"Name"}. But i dont get the data. But i see that $1 and $2 has the value. Sorry to ask. May be its very silly. But Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Note that this is all case sensitive.  $map{NAME} and $map{name} are not the same.   Also I slightly fixed the regexp as it had an issue with white space, note the '.*?' instead of the previous '.*'

Comment: if i say like the above, i get the following error, String found where operator expected at hello.pl line 30, near "say "My name is:
 ""
        (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at hello.pl line 30, near "say "My name is: ""
Execution of hello.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: yes, i gave the same value as how i defined in the txt file. Case sensitive

Comment: You can use 'print' instead of 'say'.  'say' is a more recent addition to perl and you need to declare that you want to use it.  See [perldoc say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html).

Comment: thanks i got the answer. Instead of say, i gave print. Its working. Thank you. i got the answer.